# How to handle analytics on PWA when it is deployed both as an web app and an TWA in Play Store

Tags: google-analytics, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

How should I integrate analytics into a `PWA` webapp ? if I add analytics from google analytics into webapp and publish it in a server, then later, if I want to publish it on Google Play Store, how should I track the use?

here's the scenario:

- I'm deploying the `PWA` from a subdomain.
- then I'm publishing the `PWA` from Google Play Store as a `TWA`.

My concerns:

Should I use the google analytics snippet for web to track the subdomain-based pwa and firebase analytics for my Google Play Store app?

Or,

Can I use a single method to track both versions at the same time?

I have found this [faq of chrome developer](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-app-06) about use of `google analytics`

> The CPA library follows the basic usage pattern of Google Analytics and will feel familiar to existing users of Google Analytics. However, unlike the web-centric official Google Analytics JavaScript libraries, the CPA library uses an "app-centric" model that is better suited for Packaged Apps. Among other features, the library provides methods for specific types of hits, such as "event" and "appView", and it can be used in both Closure-based and traditional JavaScript projects.

I am using `Vuejs` as frontend with `pwa` template, not sure if it is applicable for my use case. Any suggestion or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [THIS](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new-way-unify-app-and-website-measurement-google-analytics/) - Web + App configuration.

Using this you can track both at the same time.

You can configure it easily in firebase - see [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started) for more

Comment: thank you for sharing the resource. I would go through it and let you know if it works in my case. thank you very much,